# Esplora: Connecting a 2-Wire Speaker to Arduino Esplora

Tags: tft, speaker, arduino-esplora

I am currently trying to make a simple game system with my Arduino Esplora, however I have noticed something. The Arduino Esplora has no pins for a 2-pin speaker that I get from a RadioShack store [(Click here for item description)](https://www.radioshack.com/collections/maker-parts-kits/products/radioshack-8-ohm-mini-speaker?variant=5717358533). How would I go about connecting the speaker because I am also using the TFT LCD screen, or is there a workaround with the output TinkerKit pins on the top?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!